# Why this assign does not trigger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, xstate

After reading the [official xstate tutorial](https://xstate.js.org/docs/tutorials/reddit.html#putting-it-all-together), I tried to implement my own machine inspired by this post on [dev.to by one of the xstate's dev](https://dev.to/mpocock1/xstate-should-this-be-an-action-or-a-service-2cp).

Everything works as expected besides that `output` does not seem to be updated. The assignment does not do its job I think. What did I forget?

[image: Edit wandering-violet-obe1q]

To compare, here is a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xstate-react-typescript-template-wjdvn?file=/src/index.tsx:664-669) from xstate where the variable in the context is updated as expected.

more information on assign on [Context | XState Docs](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/context.html#assign-action)

my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createMachine, assign } from "xstate";
import { useMachine } from "@xstate/react";

interface FetchContext {
  output: string;
}

const fetchifetch = async () => {
  return await fetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  ).then((response) => response.json());
};

const fetchMachine = createMachine<FetchContext>({
  initial: "idle",
  context: {
    output: "wesh" // none selected
  },
  states: {
    idle: {
      on: {
        FETCH: "loading"
      }
    },
    loading: {
      invoke: {
        src: (context, event) => async (send) => {
          setTimeout(async () => {
            const data = await fetchifetch();
            console.log("done");
            console.log(data);
            // well. here I want to assign something to output
            assign({
              output: (context, event) => data.title
            });
            send("FETCHED_SUCCESSFULLY");
          }, 4000);
          console.log("start");
        },
        onError: {
          target: "idle"
        }
      },
      on: {
        FETCHED_SUCCESSFULLY: {
          target: "idle"
        }
      }
    },
    fetch: {
      on: {
        CLOSE: "idle"
      }
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  const [current, send] = useMachine(fetchMachine);
  const { output } = current.context;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>XState React Template</h1>
      <br />
      <input
        disabled={current.matches("loading")}
        defaultValue="yo"
        onChange={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <button
        disabled={current.matches("loading")}
        onClick={() => send("FETCH")}
      >
        click to fetch
      </button>

      <!-- let's display the result over here -->
      <div>{output}</div>
      <div>{current.context.output}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a Promise then and have the state machine update the context after the Promise is resolved.

The context is updated in the `onDone` property of [`invoke`](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/communication.html#the-invoke-property).

```
const fetchMachine = createMachine<FetchContext>({
  initial: "idle",
  context: {
    output: "wesh" // none selected
  },
  states: {
    idle: {
      on: {
        FETCH: "loading"
      }
    },
    loading: {
      invoke: {
        src: (context, event) => async (send) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(async () => {
              try {
                const data = await fetchifetch();
                resolve(data.title);
              } catch (err) {
                 reject(err);
              }
            }, 4000);
          });
        },
        onDone: {
          target: "fetch",
          actions: assign({
            output: (_, event) => event.data,
          })
        },
        onError: {
          target: "idle"
        }
      },
      on: {
        FETCHED_SUCCESSFULLY: {
          target: "idle",
        }
      }
    },
    fetch: {
      on: {
        CLOSE: "idle"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: We can go as far as write `invoke: { src: fetchifetch, onDone: { target: "fetch", actions: assign({ output: (_, event) => event.data.title })}, onError: { target: "idle" }}`

Comment: Yeah, I presumed the reason for the timeout was to simulate a long delay

Comment: Yes I added for that reason :)